# Table view is not populated after interstitial

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interstitial

I have a table view in my app. If i load it before to appear my interstitial the table is populated , else if i want to diplayed after  interstitial , table view is empty.

I made a debug , and i saw that : if  the interstitial is displayed , and then i want to view my table view , the method numberOfRowsInSection is never invoked.

this is my code :

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //End recieving events
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav64.png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter* emmformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [emmformatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];

    NSDateFormatter* eddformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [eddformatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];

    NSDateFormatter* eyyyyformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [eyyyyformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

    NSDateFormatter* ehhformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [ehhformatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];

    NSString * mmz= [emmformatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString * jjz= [eddformatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString * yyyyz= [eyyyyformatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString * hhz= [ehhformatter stringFromDate:date];

    //   NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"epg_cache/programme-tv-rss_%@-%@-%@.xml",yyyyz,mmz,jjz]);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theambassador.fr/"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    [httpClient postPath:@"tvlive/Bresil_20141105_150122.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
      {
         resultofData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
         test=[resultofData valueForKey:@"name"];
         self.categoryArray=[resultofData valueForKey:@"category"];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@":( " message:@"Pas d'internet !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
    }];
    NSString *titleapp = @"Programma de TV";
    self.navigationItem.title = titleapp;       
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [test count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 65.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     ChaineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chiancelelidentif"];
     cell.title.text=[test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     //cell.title.text = [[[globarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"nomchaine"];
     NSDictionary *midic = [resultofData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [cell.imag setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[midic objectForKey:@"image"]]];
     return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Uh...not sure if I am understanding your questions correctly but in the response block of your call to your server (after this line `self.categoryArray=[resultofData valueForKey:@"category"];`) could you try adding `[self.tableView reloadData];` to refresh your data ?

Comment: what value does [test count] return ?

Comment: after interstitial appears the method numberOfRowsInSection is not invoked.

Comment: Thanks @Zhang , that was the solution.